# SQL Partition by Overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table as follow and I would like to partition the table if the date is overlapped based on same member id. I use following codes but it only partition based on member id but not with overlapping dates. How to include partitioning which takes overlapping date into account as well?

```
ID MemberID StartDate   EndDate      
1  2        2015-01-01  2015-02-28
2  2        2015-02-02  2015-02-03 
3  2        2015-05-01  2015-05-20 
4  1        2015-02-01  2015-02-28 
5  2        2015-02-01  2015-03-01 


SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MEMBERID ORDER BY ID) AS GROUPID
FROM TABLENAME AS A


ID MemberID StartDate   EndDate      
1  2        2015-01-01  2015-02-28
2  2        2015-02-01  2015-02-03 
3  2        2015-05-01  2015-05-20 
4  1        2015-02-01  2015-02-28 
5  2        2015-02-01  2015-03-01
```

Current Output:

```
ID MemberID StartDate   EndDate      GROUPID
4  1        2015-02-01  2015-02-28   1
1  2        2015-01-01  2015-02-28   1
2  2        2015-02-02  2015-02-03   2
3  2        2015-05-01  2015-05-20   3
5  2        2015-02-01  2015-03-01   4
```

Expected Output:

```
ID MemberID StartDate   EndDate      GROUPID
4  1        2015-02-01  2015-02-28   1
1  2        2015-01-01  2015-02-28   1
2  2        2015-02-02  2015-02-03   2
5  2        2015-02-01  2015-02-28   3
3  2        2015-05-01  2015-05-20   1
```

Comment: See [this article](https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/gaps-in-date-ranges-when-are-you-free/) to get started. I found the SQL rather confusing, so you may find [an answer I wrote](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102071/23369) helpful.

Comment: Also, don't use snippets for SQL. They're HTML/CSS/JS only.

Comment: It seems that `GROUPID` value is being reset to `1` in row with `ID=5`. Based on what criteria does this reset take place?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos there is some mistakes in my post. I have updated it in the output

Comment: @jpmc26 it seems that i can't use lead on date range?

Comment: After the edit you made output is now completely unclear: you have placed into the same group rows with different `MemberID` values.

Comment: Also, row with `ID=2` overlaps with rows with `ID = 1,4`. How come it is placed in a separate group?

Comment: It seem like there is some error in your output. Notice that in your expected output, you have a `startDate` `2015-02-02`, but this date is not found in your original table `TABLENAME`. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos the first criteria is overlapping dates with memberid. rows with ID 2 will not overlap with rows with ID 4 because of different member ID. Perhaps there is misunderstanding here. GROUP ID with increment value is considered in same group. In other words, row 4 is 1 group, row 1,2,5 is another group and row 3 is the third group in this case. THere is reason i need the output in this way.

Comment: @Doraemon yup there is typo i have updated the table thanks for informing

Comment: *row 1,2,5 is another group* with different `GROUPID` per group member?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yup thats right. And that is the expected output that I would like to achieve and unfortunately I only able to get the output of second table currently.

Comment: Which sql server version are you using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos sql server 2012 does this makes any difference?

Comment: Yes it does, since you need `LEAD` / `LAG` to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query give the correct output:

```
WITH ord as (
    SELECT ID, MemberID
        , StartDate, EndDate
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [MemberID] order by [StartDate], [EndDate])
    FROM @data d1
), first as (
    SELECT o1.ID, o1.MemberID
        , o1.n
    FROM ord o1
    INNER JOIN ord o2 ON o1.MemberID = o2.MemberID AND o2.n+1 = o1.n AND o1.StartDate > o2.EndDate
), groups as (
    SELECT o.ID, o.MemberID
        , p = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by o.MemberID, MIN(coalesce(f.n, 1)) ORDER BY o.ID)
    FROM ord o
    LEFT JOIN first f ON o.MemberID = f.MemberID AND o.n < f.n
    GROUP BY o.ID, o.MemberID
)
SELECT g.ID, g.MemberID, d.StartDate, d.EndDate, GROUPID = g.p
FROM groups g
INNER JOIN @data d ON g.ID = d.ID
```

Note that it has to be tested with more data.

Output:

```
ID  MemberID    StartDate   EndDate     GROUPID
4   1           2015-02-01  2015-02-28  1
3   2           2015-05-01  2015-05-20  1
1   2           2015-01-01  2015-02-28  1
2   2           2015-02-02  2015-02-03  2
5   2           2015-02-01  2015-03-01  3
```

Your data:

```
declare @data table([ID] int, [MemberID] int, [StartDate] date, [EndDate] date);
Insert into @data([ID], [MemberID], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES
    (1, 2, '2015-01-01', '2015-02-28'),
    (2, 2, '2015-02-02', '2015-02-03'),
    (3, 2, '2015-05-01', '2015-05-20'),
    (4, 1, '2015-02-01', '2015-02-28'),
    (5, 2, '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01')
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a combination of window functions in order to get what you want. This is a way you can do it:

```
SELECT ID, MemberID, StartDate, EndDate,
       1 + SUM(bOverlaps) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID, grp 
                                ORDER BY EndDate) AS GroupID
FROM (                            
  SELECT ID, MemberID, StartDate, EndDate, bOverlaps,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                            ORDER BY EndDate)
         -  SUM(bOverlaps) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                                 ORDER BY EndDate) AS grp                           
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, MemberID, StartDate, EndDate,
           CASE 
              WHEN StartDate <= LAG(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                                                   ORDER BY EndDate) 
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0 
           END AS bOverlaps
    FROM mytable) AS t ) AS u
```

**Explanation:**

Consider the innermost subquery first:

```
SELECT ID, MemberID, StartDate, EndDate,
           CASE 
              WHEN StartDate <= LAG(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                                                   ORDER BY EndDate) 
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0 
           END AS bOverlaps
FROM mytable
```

**Output:**

```
ID  MemberID    StartDate   EndDate    bOverlaps
4   1           2015-02-01  2015-02-28 0
2   2           2015-02-02  2015-02-03 0
1   2           2015-01-01  2015-02-28 1
5   2           2015-02-01  2015-03-01 1
3   2           2015-05-01  2015-05-20 0
```

Calculated field `bOverlaps` is `1` (true) if current row overlaps with the immediately preceding row of the same `MemberID` partition.

Next level subquery uses the above derived table in order to calculate *islands* of consecutive overlapping records within the same `MemberID` partition.

This query:

```
SELECT ID, MemberID, StartDate, EndDate, bOverlaps,
       SUM(bOverlaps) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                            ORDER BY EndDate) AS GroupSeq,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                          ORDER BY EndDate)
       -  SUM(bOverlaps) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                               ORDER BY EndDate) AS grp      
FROM ( ... innermost derived table here ... )
```

produces the following output:

```
ID  MemberID StartDate  EndDate    bOverlaps GroupSeq grp
4   1        2015-02-01 2015-02-28 0         0        1
2   2        2015-02-02 2015-02-03 0         0        1
1   2        2015-01-01 2015-02-28 1         1        1
5   2        2015-02-01 2015-03-01 1         2        1
3   2        2015-05-01 2015-05-20 0         2        2
```

`GroupSeq` is essentially a running total of `bOverlaps` and is used in order to calculate `grp`. `grp` in the output above identifies 3 separate islands:

```
Island no. IDs    grp value
1          4      1
2          2,1,5  1
3          3      2
```

Finally, the outermost query uses this expression:

```
1 + SUM(bOverlaps) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID, grp 
                         ORDER BY EndDate) AS GroupID
```

in order to calculate `GroupID`: using a running total again we can enumerate rows belonging to the same island.

We can alternatively use `ROW_NUMBER` for the same purpose here:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID, grp 
                   ORDER BY EndDate) AS GroupID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/852171/5)